# Regular expression pattern for dates with different symbols and variable digit formats

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse out some dates in a text field that could be in the following formats (note the text field has a bunch of other junk surrounding the dates):

```
//with dashes
10-10-16
1-5-16
10-1-16
1-10-16

//with periods
10.10.16
1.5.16
10.1.16
1.10.16

//with forward slashes
10/10/16
1/5/16
10/1/16
1/10/16
```

What I need is one pattern for all digit format scenarios. Here is what I tried:

```
//x.xx.xx
Regex reg1 = new Regex (@"\(?\d{1}\)?[-/.]? *\d{2}[-/.]? *[-/.]?\d{2}")

//xx.xx.xx
Regex reg2 = new Regex (@"\(?\d{2}\)?[-/.]? *\d{2}[-/.]? *[-/.]?\d{2}")

//x.x.xx
Regex reg3 = new Regex (@"\(?\d{1}\)?[-/.]? *\d{1}[-/.]? *[-/.]?\d{2}")

//xx.x.xx
Regex reg4 = new Regex (@"\(?\d{2}\)?[-/.]? *\d{1}[-/.]? *[-/.]?\d{2}")
```

I'm new to regular expressions, so I am looking for a single expression that will handle all these scenarios (ie., digit formats with single number and double digit numbers for -/. in between).

Is there one expression that could handle this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\(?(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\)?[-/.]?\d{1,2}[-/.]?\d{2}(?!\d)");
```

If your date separators are used consistently, use the backreference with a capturing group:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\(?(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\)?([-/.])\d{1,2}\1\d{2}(?!\d)");
```

See the [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/GUWKVu/1) and [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/GUWKVu/3).

**Details**:

- `\(?` - an optional `(`
- `(?<!\d)` - there must be no digit before the current location
- `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `\)?` - an optional `)`
- `[-/.]?` - an optional `-`, `/`, or `.`
- `\d{1,2}[-/.]?` - ibid.
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `(?!\d)` - there must be no digit after the current location.

The version with a capturing group/backreference contains `([-/.])` - a capturing group with ID=1 that matches the first separator, and `\1` is the backreference that matches the same text captured into Group 1 (making the second separator to be identical to the first one).

Comment: If your date separators are used consistently, use the backreference with a capturing group - `Regex rx = new Regex(@"\(?(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\)?([-/.]?)\d{1,2}\1\d{2}(?!\d)");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this: [`\d{1,2}([-./])\d{1,2}\1\d{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/0ncJ4N/2)

`Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}([-./])\d{1,2}\1\d{2}");`

- `\d{1,2}` between one and two digits
- `([-./])` any of `.`, `-` and `/`
- `\1` repeat this character another time to (prevent matching `1.1/01` or `1-1.01`)
- `\d{2}` matches two digits

Comment: I also thought about posting that pattern as an alternative, but backreferences are more restrictive, while repeating the `[-./]` character class will find matches in looser contexts.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
\d{1,2}(-|\.|\/)\d{1,2}(-|\.|\/)\d{1,2}
```